# what does "barely below the surface" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> After an enormous argument, the two boys set off for home, in silence, their anger barely below the surface the whole time.

what does "barely below the surface" mean?

I have two guesses:

- they couldn't hide their anger
- their anger was very high

Comment: What does it mean when a submarine is "barely below the surface"?

Answer (score -1):

They are struggling to hide their anger, maybe their facial expression is showing but they are holding themselves. 
Also it might be referring to the anger iceberg (i googled "anger below the surface")

Comment: never heard of 'anger iceberg' - could you show us what definitions the googling showed?